How can I get Postgres use my functional index
I have the following table:
CREATE TABLE items
(
    id NUMERIC(20, 0) NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXTVAL('items_sequence') PRIMARY KEY,
    item_price NUMERIC(19, 2) DEFAULT NULL NULL,
    status NUMERIC(2, 0) NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

with the following index:
CREATE INDEX items_dash_idx ON items (status, DATE(created_at));

I want to group my items per status and per day, for ~ 30 days. This means that I want to get the count and total item price per day per status for the last 30 days, including where the count/amount is 0. I have 5 statuses, one of which (50) is irrelevant and has too many rows (e.g. Status 50 has ~400k rows where statuses 10, 20, 30 and 40 has ~1k, for the last 30 days).
I have the following query:
SELECT COUNT(i.id)                    AS count,
       COALESCE(SUM(i.item_price), 0) AS amount,
       dates_table.status,
       dates_table.created_at
FROM (SELECT created_at::DATE AS created_at, 10 AS status
      FROM GENERATE_SERIES('2024-09-18'::DATE, '2024-10-18'::DATE, INTERVAL '1 DAY') AS created_at
      UNION
      SELECT created_at::DATE AS created_at, 20 AS status
      FROM GENERATE_SERIES('2024-09-18'::DATE, '2024-10-18'::DATE, INTERVAL '1 DAY') AS created_at
      UNION
      SELECT created_at::DATE AS created_at, 30 AS status
      FROM GENERATE_SERIES('2024-09-18'::DATE, '2024-10-18'::DATE, INTERVAL '1 DAY') AS created_at
      UNION
      SELECT created_at::DATE AS created_at, 40 AS status
      FROM GENERATE_SERIES('2024-09-18'::DATE, '2024-10-18'::DATE, INTERVAL '1 DAY') AS created_at
     ) AS dates_table
LEFT JOIN items i 
       ON i.status = dates_table.status
      AND DATE(i.created_at) = dates_table.created_at
GROUP BY dates_table.created_at, dates_table.status
ORDER BY dates_table.created_at, dates_table.status;

and this query seems to take 10+ seconds, with the following EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) output:
QUERY PLAN
Sort  (cost=2242005.05..2242006.05 rows=400 width=48) (actual time=21950.589..21950.601 rows=72 loops=1)
  Sort Key: dates_table.created_at, dates_table.status
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 29kB
  Buffers: shared hit=676950 read=747852 dirtied=755, temp read=28515 written=28531
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=2241982.76..2241987.76 rows=400 width=48) (actual time=21950.436..21950.492 rows=72 loops=1)
        Group Key: dates_table.created_at, dates_table.status
        Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 61kB
        Buffers: shared hit=676947 read=747852 dirtied=755, temp read=28515 written=28531
        ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=2161026.21..2239512.33 rows=247043 width=20) (actual time=21834.112..21948.382 rows=11066 loops=1)
              Merge Cond: ((dates_table.created_at = (date(i.created_at))) AND (((dates_table.status)::numeric) = i.status))
              Buffers: shared hit=676947 read=747852 dirtied=755, temp read=28515 written=28531
              ->  Sort  (cost=449.35..459.35 rows=4000 width=8) (actual time=895.905..895.933 rows=72 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: dates_table.created_at, ((dates_table.status)::numeric)
                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 28kB
                    Buffers: shared hit=4
                    ->  Subquery Scan on dates_table  (cost=130.03..210.03 rows=4000 width=8) (actual time=895.792..895.846 rows=72 loops=1)
                          ->  HashAggregate  (cost=130.03..170.03 rows=4000 width=8) (actual time=895.788..895.831 rows=72 loops=1)
                                Group Key: ((created_ai.created_at)::date), (10)
                                Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 217kB
                                ->  Append  (cost=0.01..110.03 rows=4000 width=8) (actual time=895.697..895.749 rows=72 loops=1)
                                      ->  Function Scan on generate_series created_at  (cost=0.01..12.51 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=895.694..895.697 rows=18 loops=1)
                                      ->  Function Scan on generate_series created_at_1  (cost=0.01..12.51 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=0.012..0.014 rows=18 loops=1)
                                      ->  Function Scan on generate_series created_at_2  (cost=0.01..12.51 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=0.010..0.012 rows=18 loops=1)
                                      ->  Function Scan on generate_series created_at_3  (cost=0.01..12.51 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=0.010..0.012 rows=18 loops=1)
              ->  Materialize  (cost=2160576.87..2185898.76 rows=5064379 width=25) (actual time=19123.895..20601.926 rows=5066445 loops=1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=676943 read=747852 dirtied=755, temp read=28515 written=28531
                    ->  Sort  (cost=2160576.87..2173237.82 rows=5064379 width=25) (actual time=19123.888..20125.620 rows=5066445 loops=1)
                          Sort Key: (date(i.created_at)), i.status
                          Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 228120kB
                          Buffers: shared hit=676943 read=747852 dirtied=755, temp read=28515 written=28531
                          ->  Seq Scan on items i  (cost=0.00..1475438.79 rows=5064379 width=25) (actual time=0.064..16526.846 rows=5066445 loops=1)
                                Buffers: shared hit=676943 read=747852 dirtied=755
Planning Time: 0.399 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 44
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 2.096 ms, Inlining 293.474 ms, Optimization 383.558 ms, Emission 218.758 ms, Total 897.885 ms
Execution Time: 21989.150 ms

and my cache hit ratio drops to 50% from 99.9% when I run this query. The same index (obviously TRUNC(created_at) instead of DATE(created_at)) in Oracle and the same query works in around ~500ms.
Update:
SELECT COUNT(i.id) AS count,
       SUM(i.item_price) AS amount,
       DATE(i.created_at) AS created_at,
       i.status AS status
FROM items i
WHERE i.status = 10 
AND DATE(i.created_at) >= '2024-10-01'
GROUP BY i.status, DATE(i.created_at)
ORDER BY i.status, DATE(i.created_at)

is fast with the following EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) output:
QUERY PLAN
GroupAggregate  (cost=0.43..27.72 rows=9 width=49) (actual time=0.044..0.117 rows=9 loops=1)
  Output: count(id), sum(item_price), (date(created_at)), status
  Group Key: i.status, date(i.created_at)
  Buffers: shared hit=26
  ->  Index Scan using items_dash_idx  on tenant_xxx.items i  (cost=0.43..27.49 rows=9 width=21) (actual time=0.025..0.097 rows=24 loops=1)
        Output: date(created_at), status, id, item_price
        Index Cond: ((i.status = '10'::numeric) AND (date(i.created_at) >= '2024-10-01'::date))
        Buffers: shared hit=26
Settings: effective_cache_size = '16GB', search_path = 'tenant_xxx', work_mem = '32MB'
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=3
Planning Time: 0.255 ms
Execution Time: 0.140 ms

Update #2:
If I filter the items beforehand, and then perform the join:
WITH items_table AS (SELECT COUNT(i.id)        AS count,
                            SUM(i.item_price)  AS amount,
                            DATE(i.created_at) AS created_at,
                            i.status           AS status
                     FROM items t
                     WHERE i.status IN (10, 20, 30, 40)
                       AND DATE(i.created_at) >= '2024-10-01'
                       AND DATE(i.created_at) < '2024-10-18'::DATE + INTERVAL '1 DAY'
                     GROUP BY i.status, DATE(i.created_at)
                     ORDER BY i.status, DATE(i.created_at))
SELECT dates_table.created_at          AS created_at,
       dates_table.status              AS status,
       COALESCE(items_table.count, 0)  AS count,
       COALESCE(items_table.amount, 0) AS amount
FROM (SELECT created_at::DATE               AS created_at
           , UNNEST(ARRAY [10, 20, 30, 40]) AS status
      FROM GENERATE_SERIES('2024-10-01'::DATE, '2024-10-18'::DATE, '1 DAY') AS created_at) AS dates_table
         LEFT JOIN items_table ON items_table.status = dates_table.status AND
                                  items_table.created_at = dates_table.created_at
ORDER BY dates_table.created_at, dates_table.status

it returns in around ~100ms.

i believe you need to do some research on indexes, also generate series take a lot of time, a date table, wpuld reduce the speed extremly

The GENERATE_SERIES part (the inner formation of dates_table) takes around 1ms.

That query cannot run. What is t? Besides, we'd need EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) output.

I think part of the problem is status is a numeric and you are searching for values 10, 20, 30 and 40. However, that leaves every other number between 10 and 40 (eg. 12, 10.01, etc) values of status that you do not want. Without knowing the distribution of values in status it's hard to say if it is useful or not. It could be that the index is entirely useless for the query. If status is an enum, then you should type in a way that restricts it to these values.

What is the performance of query without the filling in of missing status and created_at values? That is, just SELECT count(id), sum(item_price), status, created_at FROM items WHERE ... GROUP BY status, created_at. If it's fast, then you'll have a better time just doing that query as a nested query and subsequently right joining on all possible status/created_at pairs.

@Dunes it is the same without COALESCE. status is an enum, I have 5 statuses, one of which is irrelevant and has the most rows. The others are similar in row count. I didn't get the restriction part.

You could filter and aggregate before joining to the calendar, then coalesce() mismatches to 0's as suggested by @Dunes (in which case, the index is used) and generate your calendar once and let the target statuses unnest() for each day to simplify the query:
demo at db<>fiddle
WITH calendar AS
   (SELECT created_at::date
         , unnest(array[10,20,30,40]) AS status
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES('2024-09-18'::date,'2024-10-18','1 DAY') AS created_at)
,pre_agg AS
   (SELECT COUNT(i.id)                    AS count,
           COALESCE(SUM(i.item_price), 0) AS amount,
           i.status,
           date(i.created_at) as created_at
    FROM items i 
    WHERE i.status=any(array[10,20,30,40])
      AND date(i.created_at) between '2024-09-18' and '2024-10-18'
    GROUP BY date(i.created_at), i.status )
SELECT created_at
     , status
     , coalesce(count,0) as count
     , coalesce(amount,0) as amount
FROM calendar 
LEFT JOIN pre_agg 
    USING(created_at,status)
ORDER BY created_at,status;




QUERY PLAN




Sort  (cost=6419.03..6429.03 rows=4000 width=76) (actual time=48.105..48.121 rows=124 loops=1)


Output: ((created_at.created_at)::date), (((unnest('{10,20,30,40}'::integer[])))::numeric), (COALESCE(pre_agg.count, '0'::bigint)), (COALESCE(pre_agg.amount, '0'::numeric))


Sort Key: ((created_at.created_at)::date), (((unnest('{10,20,30,40}'::integer[])))::numeric)


Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 34kB


->  Hash Left Join  (cost=6068.21..6179.71 rows=4000 width=76) (actual time=47.844..48.054 rows=124 loops=1)


Output: ((created_at.created_at)::date), (unnest('{10,20,30,40}'::integer[])), COALESCE(pre_agg.count, '0'::bigint), COALESCE(pre_agg.amount, '0'::numeric)


Inner Unique: true


Hash Cond: ((((created_at.created_at)::date) = pre_agg.created_at) AND (((unnest('{10,20,30,40}'::integer[])))::numeric = pre_agg.status))


->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.01..40.01 rows=4000 width=8) (actual time=0.028..0.120 rows=124 loops=1)


Output: (created_at.created_at)::date, unnest('{10,20,30,40}'::integer[])


->  Function Scan on pg_catalog.generate_series created_at  (cost=0.01..10.01 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=0.025..0.031 rows=31 loops=1)


Output: created_at.created_at


Function Call: generate_series(('2024-09-18'::date)::timestamp with time zone, '2024-10-18 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone, '1 day'::interval)


->  Hash  (cost=5948.04..5948.04 rows=8011 width=48) (actual time=47.796..47.798 rows=124 loops=1)


Output: pre_agg.count, pre_agg.amount, pre_agg.created_at, pre_agg.status


Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 72kB


->  Subquery Scan on pre_agg  (cost=5747.76..5948.04 rows=8011 width=48) (actual time=47.532..47.730 rows=124 loops=1)


Output: pre_agg.count, pre_agg.amount, pre_agg.created_at, pre_agg.status


->  HashAggregate  (cost=5747.76..5867.93 rows=8011 width=48) (actual time=47.530..47.703 rows=124 loops=1)


Output: count(i.id), COALESCE(sum(i.item_price), '0'::numeric), i.status, (date(i.created_at))


Group Key: date(i.created_at), i.status


Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 465kB


->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.items i  (cost=521.68..5562.67 rows=18509 width=28) (actual time=5.149..36.145 rows=18355 loops=1)


Output: i.status, date(i.created_at), i.id, i.item_price


Recheck Cond: ((i.status = ANY ('{10,20,30,40}'::numeric[])) AND (date(i.created_at) >= '2024-09-18'::date) AND (date(i.created_at) <= '2024-10-18'::date))


Heap Blocks: exact=1074


->  Bitmap Index Scan on items_dash_idx  (cost=0.00..517.05 rows=18509 width=0) (actual time=4.917..4.918 rows=18355 loops=1)


Index Cond: ((i.status = ANY ('{10,20,30,40}'::numeric[])) AND (date(i.created_at) >= '2024-09-18'::date) AND (date(i.created_at) <= '2024-10-18'::date))


Planning Time: 0.554 ms


Execution Time: 48.340 ms



